# Metamask from web to mobile

Tags: metamask

I have use my PC to manage MetaMask (ie. chrome extend). compound.finance also connect to my metamask wallet. I want to  manage my account by mobile and at PC that I install metamask mobile in andriod. But the mobile version create a new wallet to me. How to use mobile to manage my previous wallet ?  Will the compound finance cannot connect my wallet after use mobile version ?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to save / backup your seed words (12 random english words that are in your Metamask settings) from your desktop, and import them into your mobile metamask.

Better yet, ask Compound to support a web wallet that is backed up remotely (e.g. Portis, Fortmatic, Torus, or Democracy)